# How can i edit the order table in the plain text email that is sent when a customer places an new order in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

So i'm using the default email that WooCommerce sends to the admin when a new order has been placed. In this email this hook is being called: 
`do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, true, false );` which i guess generates the order table.

I want to change the layout of the table. But i can't seem to find where Woocommerce actually generates the html.
Where can i find it and what is the best to edit it?

thnx for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For chnage mail html you need to check below files.

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-header.php
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-items.php
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-footer.php
```

Comment: Thanks. i need to be in admin-new-order.php. But it again calls another hook. I think i need to dig futher, any idea where?

Comment: for that you need to check code and track hook call function. how i told how to get?

Comment: you understood my last answer or still finding answer?